# Is it just me or has there not been a question in over 2 days?

Tags: discussion

The last question I see is the question I asked about the Scotch Game.  Is it just me or is that in fact the last question that was asked?  What are we to make of this?

Answer (score 5):

We need to attract more people to the site rather than rely on more questions from the existing community.

Sometimes you just don't have questions. I've been a member of stackoverflow for a long time and have only ever asked 2 questions.